# virtualized shared folder on IIS ERROR HTTP 401.3 - Unauthorized

Tags: angular, iis, authorization, shared-directory

I am developing a web application on Angular and IIS which enables the users to download the files inside a shared folder. I virtualized on IIS the shared folder and when I try to visualize the folder on the browser I get ERROR HTTP 401.3 - Unauthorized,
but my local user (and also everyone users) has the complete access enabled on the folder properties .
On iis I tried to change the application pool user and on the virtualized folder authentication panel I tried both with anonymus and windows authentication.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: IIS does not support any mapped drives or third party "virtualized folder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a windwos network user and using this user credentials on IIS application pool authentication identity. In order to make it work, you have to set as auth method of the virtualized folder, the base authentication method. Obviusly your user and network user must have access to your shared folder.